# Android Power Manager Wake Lock

Tags: java, android, power-management, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I've got application which is playing TV streams and needs to be ON all the time.
I do acquire wake lock in OnCreate()

```
pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
wl.acquire();
```

and then release in onDestroy()

```
if (wl != null) {
    wl.release();
    wl = null;
}
```

User usually minimize the app by pressing back, home or power button
and then resumes from home screen tapping the app icon.
I do release wake lock in onPause() and acquire in onResume().

Time to time I see application crashes or disappears completely from screen and I see
logs related to wake lock.

Is this a best practice to control Android Power Manager Wake Lock?

Any opinions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

As you are saying that you do release wake lock in `onPause()` and acquire in `onResume()`. That is a good practice however alongwith these I suggest you to release wakelock in `onUserLeaveHint()` as well.

[onUserLeaveHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29)

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {

try {
     // your code.

     // release the wake lock
     wl.release();

    }catch(Exception ex){
     Log.e("Exception in onUserLeaveHint", ex.getMessage);
    }
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Then use this in your oncreate after setContentView:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Should help.

Comment: I guess this solves the fact that old Power Manager constants are deprecated now. My main point is what is the best practice to handle wake lock. When user pressed Power button, wake lock is released by framework. I guess this is not happen when minimizing app by back or home button. Is it?

Comment: Based on experience, this line of code is enough to hold the wakelock for your activity. It holds the lock as long as the window is visible.

No need to handle the wake lock on lifecycle yourself.

Answer (score 1):

additional to silvia_aut's answer, try

```
if (wakelock.isHeld())
       wakelock.release();
```

Comment: If you do it this way, your pm and wl variables can be local. Get your instance like you already have `wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);` and just look if it is hold or not.

Comment: yes, that's what I've done. Thanks, I am happy with feedback.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
```

and dont forget permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: thanks, but I can't use DIM. Otherwise, it's same as my solution.